# How to search for underscore character in Windows Search?

Tags: windows-search

I have Windows 10. I want to use Explorer Search to find file containing Arr__

It is important to have the 2 underscore.

however, it returns Arr_SOMETHING

So even those with one underscore are returned and I do not want them

How do I make Windows 10 Explorer Search to return me exclusively files containing Arr__ ?

Comment: Don't know if you can be that precise from Taskbar/Start Menu Search, but if you mean **Explorer** Search, the syntax: `name:~"ARR__*"` should do the trick...

Comment: @KeithMiller thx a million! I corrected my question to indicate Explorer Search and changed the tag. The only problem I have now is I don't want file with the name, but containing said characters? If you know and can post this as an answer I will approve it.

Comment: Do you mean you want the names of all files with `__` in the *name* or `Arr__` in the *content* of a text file?

Comment: @KeithMiller I actually want every file containing Arr__ but not Arr_

Comment: If you want everything containing `Arr__`  (including, for example, file names like `fooARR__foo`) then you just need to add another asterisk: `name:~"*ARR__*"`